# How do notifications traverse a Puppet resource chain?

Tags: puppet

Given this simplified Puppet example, it's clear that any change to `my_file` will trigger `my_service` to refresh due to the `~>` chaining operator:

```
package { 'my_package': }
->
file { 'my_file': }
~>
service { 'my_service': }
```

Will a change to `my_package` also cause `my_service` to refresh? (That is, will the state change propagate through a non-notifying `->` chain operator?)

I know that refresh events will propagate through a chain if all the operators are notifying operators, but the documentation isn't clear how it works in a mixed chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notifications *never* propagate through another resource, even if they are in a chain of resources set to notify.

When a resource is "changed", then it notifies any resources subscribed to its own change. Those resources have a `refresh` method called on them, that does whatever that type requires. After that nothing else happens.

If a notified resource is changed *itself*, then it will also notify anyone subscribed to *it's* change. This isn't propagating a notification, it is really propagating *changes* going through the manifest.

As an example, if `/tmp/markerfile` already exists this manifest will not apply the exec resource:

```
notify { 'test': }
~>
file { '/tmp/markerfile':
  ensure => present
}
~>
exec { '/bin/date':
  refreshonly => true
}
```

Comment: So in example my case, say `my_package` was nginx, `my_file` is the nginx config file and `my_service` is the nginx service. If for some reason the nginx config file already existed, the installation of the package would never trigger the start of the service? I guess that makes sense, but it's confusing with so many chaining examples out there with a final `~>` at the end for a service.

Comment: @ScottSB In that case you would still start the service (if it is not already running and `ensure => running`). Notifying a service would *restart* an already running service. So in your example, it would not restart an already running service. That's a bit of a corner case, because if the package was not installed then the service was likely not running anyways and will be started by the service resource.

Comment: You're right. I still feel like this leaves some surprising edge cases out there, but it's not worth trying to identify them now that I know the behavior. I'll just make sure to directly notify from any resource that may need to refresh a service (or exec).

Comment: I'd suggest changing the first sentence (cannot edit right now though). **Notifications are passed on to contained resources**. See this doc for relationships between resources https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_relationships.html